# How to return a result in ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using ZXing API.

I have the following code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                integrator.setPrompt("Para usar o flash utilizar os botões do volume");
                integrator.initiateScan();
```

However, I don't know how to publish the initiateScan using the ActivityResultLauncher mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent().

Could you please help me?
Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

I add:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLaucher;

activityResultLaucher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                }
            }
        });
```

and:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                integrator.setPrompt("Para usar o flash utilizar os botões do volume");
                integrator.initiateScan();
                ActivityResultLauncher.launch(integrator);
                }

             });
```

But the ActivityResultLauncher.launch(integrator) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch scanner with 'integrator.createScanIntent()'.

`activityResultLaucher.launch(integrator.createScanIntent());`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                integrator.setPrompt("Para usar o flash utilizar os botões do volume");
                // integrator.initiateScan(); <- remove this line

                // launch scanner with 'integrator.createScanIntent()'
                activityResultLaucher.launch(integrator.createScanIntent());
              }

             });
```